# Would a GAMMA or Negative Binomial Generalized Linear Model be the right test for my data?

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, generalized-linear-model, biostatistics

I want to compare the Perkins Eye Index (PEI) values, a measure of lobster egg development, between the months of January to June 2023. This is because I want to test the hypothesis that PEI varies significantly month by month, providing insights into the nature of the lobster spawning season.

My dataset contains two variables: Month (Jan to Jun) and PEI. There are a range of 4 to 22 PEI values per month.

The PEI values (across all months) are not normally distributed: Anderson-Darling normality test, data:  data$PEI
A = 2.173, p-value = 1.47e-05

And looking at a histogram, it seems skewed with outliers (see below)
[image]

My PEI values are overdispersed too (dispersion parameter of 59.66303)

**Considering all the information, would a GAMMA Generalized Linear Model be a good test for my hypothesis?

Or considering the overdispersion, would a negative binomial GLM be better?

Any advice would be greatly appreciated before I crack on with my dissertation!**

Comment: It would seem there are a few reasons in play when choosing a distribution: 1) the data generating mechanism -- if known; 2) given a distribution - what are its theoretical assumptions and how do they map into your data; 3) and empirical fit -- choose the distribution which minimizes the error or loss. That said, why do you have to limit the choice to just one? It would be much more interesting to discuss both distributions in the context of your study, don't you think?

Comment: Hi @MikeHunter , thank you for your response, though as a novice, I'd like to work with just one of the two models for now. Would you be able to confirm whether the GAMMA or Negative Binomial GLM would be best/work for my study? Cheers

Comment: Nope...that's for your dissertation.

Comment: Gamma is a continuous distribution. NB is an integer distribution. What is more appropriate for your data?

Comment: Expanding on @Alex's point, negative binomial isn't  suitable unless you're counting PEI.  Two more general points: 1. The marginal distribution of an outcome doesn't necessarily indicate the best family of distributions; rather the focus should be on the conditional distributions of the outcome given predictors. 2. Your distribution looks bimodal to me, which often but not always implies some sort of mixture, which comes down to the biology here. Either way, none of the distributions mentioned can be bimodal, although that may well be resolved by looking at predictors. See point 1 again.